# How to get " in TeXnicCenter with auto-replacement for quotation marks enabled

Tags: punctuation, texniccenter

I usually appreciate TeXnicCenter's feature of automatically replacing `"` with ``` `` ``` and `''`, but sometimes I actually need `"` in the source, e.g. in `"|` to prevent a ligature. Is there a clever way (like a special key combination) to achieve this?

(Obviously, changing the TeXnicCenter setting is not an option. So far, I'd open up notepad real quick and type, copy, and paste `"`, but I'm looking for a more efficient way.)

I use TeXnicCenter 1.0 RC 1.

Comment: It doesn't appear "Own Text Module" in TC alpha, just "Manage Text Modules", does anyone know how to get this nice customization in TC alpha? Thanks!

Comment: @user5492 [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Your question won't be seen by many people here so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. Follow-up questions like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Comment: Welcome from me, too. I agree that this shouldn't be an answer, but the issue here might be so minute that it can easily be solved in a comment. Did you define your own text module first? For that, the precise order of clicks is: `Insert`⇒`Own Text Modules`⇒`Manage Text Modules` (in TXC 1.0 Stable Release Candidate 1). A restart of TXC might be required in between defining the text module and assigning the shortcut to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a really comfortable way, but if you don't have to use the `"` symbol too often, you could use a text module:

1. Go to `Insert->Own Text Modules->Manage Text Modules...`
2. Create a `New` text module like this:

   [image: dialog window]
3. Click `OK` to confirm your changes.

From now on, you can insert the `"` symbol at the current position using `Insert->Own Text Modules->Straight quotation mark`.

Comment: That's great! Starting from there, you can even assign a custom keyboard shortcut, you just have to make sure the straight quotes text module is the first, alphabetically (e.g. by putting a `1` in front of its name). Then go to `Tools->Customize->Keyboard->Category:Insert->Own Text Module` and assign whatever shortcut is desired.
This makes `"` pretty comfortable to type, but it only works for one text module.