# Is there a reason shift+' writes " ' instead of just "?

Tags: texniccenter

I was writing something about using Moebius inversion, and to get the correct symbol I write `\"{o}` to get the umlaut over the o. However, in TeXnicCenter, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> automatically writes `"'` instead of the desired `"`. Is there a reason for this? I always have to delete the extra apostrophe each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a setting of [TeXnicCenter (v1.0 Stable RC 1)](http://www.texniccenter.org/) that can be activated/deactivated. Under `Tools -> Options -> General -> Automatic replacement` you need to **deactivate** `Replace quotation marks`:

[image: TeXnicCenter settings]

Comment: Or set it to something else.

Comment: If you want to keep the auto-replacement, take a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15483/how-to-get-in-texniccenter-with-auto-replacement-for-quotation-marks-enabled

Comment: Since @yunone asked for the reason for this behavior as well: This is an auto-replacement feature for quotation marks, in your case apparently enabled for German quotation marks. Quotation marks need to be masked specially in LaTeX: `"\`Zitat"'` (German) / `\`\`Quote''` (English). For your convenience, TeXnicCenter offers a feature where a typed `"` is automatically replaced with either opening or closing quotation marks, with options available for a few languages or your own choice.