# How to avoid getting "` when typing " in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a reason shift+' writes " ' instead of just "?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25365/is-there-a-reason-shift-writes-instead-of-just)

I'm using Windows 7 with TeXnicCenter 1.0 stable release candidate 1. I changed my keyboard from US-international to US, because this means a `^` gets immediately displayed when typing. But now, when typing `"`, I get ``"`, which it quite irritating in BibTeX.

What is happening, and how to prevent it?

Comment: A very similar question has actually been asked here already, the only difference is that it's referring to closing quotation marks instead of opening: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25365/is-there-a-reason-shift-writes-instead-of-just. This should help you with your answer and I think we can close this question. Let us know if you need further help!

Comment: Yes, I think we can close this question.